# Discussion Board Subject View displaying "Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist."

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-discussion-board

We did a database upgrade from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010.  We are still using the 2007 interface.  After the upgrade there's a problem with one of our discussion boards:
  The discussion board is included as a web part on the landing page of one of our sites.  It works there, no problem.  However, if you click on the title of the web part to bring you to the default view for the discussion board (Subject View.aspx), you get an error screen with "Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist."

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question because I couldn't find the answer anywhere.  Everything was either in relation to disposing the current site or [KB 2575303](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2575303).  This was *not* my problem.

It turns out that I had to delete the view and create a new one.  (Note, you cannot delete a default view, you must set another view as the default.  When the view is no longer a default view you should be able to delete it.)

- How to add/create views when you can't even get to the discussion board page?

  Site Actions --> Site Settings

  Under "Site Administration" click on "Content and Structure"

  Mouse over the discussion board, click the down arrow and then click "Edit Poperties"

In a shocking turn of events [office.microsoft.com was actually helpful](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-foundation-help/create-customize-and-moderate-a-discussion-board-HA101808839.aspx#_Toc263849473).

- If you are creating a Subject View, make sure that the Folders
  section is set to "In the top-level folder"
- If you are creating a Flat View, make sure that the Folders section is set to "In folders of content type Discussion"
- If you are creating a Threaded View, make sure that the Folders section is set to "In folders of content type Discussion"

Failure to follow the above settings may result in the error "Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist."

I ended up deleting the three default views; "Subject View", "Flat View" and "Threaded View" and creating new ones.

One odd thing, my original problem was with the Subject View - I couldn't create a new subject view without getting the "Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist" error.  However, since replacing the views, I haven't been able to replicate the "Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist" error with the Subject View...

Final notes:  If choosing the wrong option for "Folders" results in an error - why are the options all available?  Shouldn't they be greyed out or hidden?